# Using 'find' to email me those files modified recently

Tags: linux, bash

I'm using 'find' at the end of a script to email me any .log files in the current directory that have been modified in the last 6 hours.  I need this because the file names change so I can't be any more specific than requesting the recently changed ones.

eg,

```
for file in `find ./*.log -type f -mmin -360` ; do mail -s "MY LOG FILE - $file" me@mydomain.com  < $file ; done
```

...and it works sometimes, but more often it doesn't work even when I know there is a file in the directory that fits the criteria (having just been modified).

Any ideas why it's not working consistently for me?

Comment: how large are those modified files?
depending on your mail setup you might have a limit there, though you should be able to tell by checking your mail logfiles.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
find ./*.log -type f -mmin -360 | \
     xargs -n 1 -I % sh -c 'mail -s "MY LOG FILE - %" me@mydomain.com  < %'
```